# Log out asp.net incomplete

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, authentication, logout

I'm having this annoying problem that when i log out from asp mvc web application it's not working to 
logging again.

Log out method looks like:

```
private static void LogOut()
{   
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
 Session.Clear();
 Session.Abandon();
 Response.Cookies.Clear();
 Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```

is that cookies does not allow to login again?

Comment: What is preventing you to login? what issue you have?

Comment: i supose that clearing the browser cache is incomplete and cookies remains one way..

Comment: Check my answer regarding cookie clearance.

Comment: The `Cookies.Clear()` only removes cookies from the Response, it doesn't remove them from the client (browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the cookie expiry date to past to make the cookie invalid.

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();

// clear authentication cookie using expiration date
HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

// clear session cookie, if needed
HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);

FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

[Forms Authentication Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)